# How to convert an Unmanaged Image to a managed bitmap image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

Hi I need to convert an unmanaged image to a managed bitmap image which I need to display on a picturebox but I it seems to throw an exception saying "object reference not set to an instance of an object". Does anyone have an idea about it? I have commented the line which throws the exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
                    {
                        area = characters[i].Area;
                        UnmanagedImage numer = characters[i].Image;
                        System.Drawing.Image plateImage = numer.ToManagedImage();//Exception
                        numberplate = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(plateImage));
                        pictureBox2.Image = numberplate;
                        pictureBox2.Refresh();                            
                    }
```

I am using Aforge.net framework with C#

**UPDATE**

```
for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
                    {
                        area = characters[i].Area;
                        Bitmap numer = characters[i].Image.ToManagedImage();
                        //System.Drawing.Image plateImage = numer.ToManagedImage();
                        //numberplate = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(plateImage));
                        pictureBox2.Image = numberplate;
                        pictureBox2.Refresh();                            
                    }
```

Comment: What type is the `characters` array?

Comment: According to the [API documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/2e7a1649-557d-d716-637d-29ec276603c8.htm) the `Blob.Image` may be `null`, and in that case you could try with either of the `BlobCounter.ExtractBlobsImage` overloads.

Comment: Are all `characters` objects equal to `null`? If not, you could first filter away those that are (`var filteredChars = characters.Where(c => c != null).ToArray();`) and loop over `filteredChars` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this code on the Aforge.Net forums and it seemed to work.

```
                    BlobCounterBase bc = new BlobCounter();
                    bc.FilterBlobs = true;
                    bc.MinHeight = 5;
                    bc.MinWidth = 5;

                    bc.ProcessImage(numberplate);
                    Blob[] blobs = bc.GetObjectsInformation();
                    MessageBox.Show(bc.ObjectsCount.ToString());
                    for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        if (blobs.Length > 0)
                        {

                            bc.ExtractBlobsImage(numberplate, blobs[i], true);

                            Bitmap copy = blobs[i].Image.ToManagedImage();
                            pictureBox2.Image = numberplate;
                            pictureBox2.Refresh();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap managedImage = numer.ToManagedImage( );
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion still throws the exception

Comment: What is characters?? may be it is is list of managedImage...so UnmanagedImage numer = characters[i].Image; this may not be creating any object. Try debugging..

Comment: i have updated the code and it exits from where i convert toManagedImage(). And characters array is an array of blobs.

Comment: take your previous code and set breakpoint al line 4 and start debugger.from line 4 onward take one step and keep watching values of variables.you'll come to know where error is occuring.

Comment: I have debugged the code the previous code seem to return anull value to the unmanaged variable